# Why does my algorithm stop after a while?

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I wrote an Algorithm to guess a number the user inputs:

```
import random

def innum(x):
    innumber = ""
    for y in range(x):
        innumber += str(y)
    return innumber

def ml():
    wrong = ""
    while True:
        guess = start
        action = random.choice(["+","-"])
        if action == "+":
            guess += random.randint(0,1000)
        if action == "-":
            guess -= random.randint(0,1000)
        if "-" not in str(guess):
            if str(guess) not in wrong:
                if guess == answer:
                    print("Correct: " + str(answer))
                    break
                else:
                    print("Wrong:" + str(guess))
                    wrong += str(guess)
start = random.randint(0,1000)
answer = input("What number to go to from " + str(start) + ". Has to be in range 2000.")
if answer in innum(2000):
        ml()
else:
     print("Number not in range 2000.")
```

But after a while it just stops I ran it multiple times and it keeps stopping and never gets a answer. I read the program multiple times and I still don't know why it stops.

Comment: Whats ```ai()```

Comment: Fixed it sorry I changed the names a while ago

Comment: Try adding the following two debug prints after `if "-" not in str(guess`: `print("Got here, str(guess) is " + str(guess))` and `print("Got here, wrong is " + wrong)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing, I would assume that the condition `if str(guess) not in wrong:` is never true after some time of execution. Since the program will with time populate the `wrong` with many different combinations of digits, the `str(guess)` will eventually be somewhere among the `wrong`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `if str(guess) not in wrong:` will check if the value is not in the string. But once it encounters the value, the `if` statement returns `False` and hence the program halts. However there is no halting in the `while` loop.